# How do you debug Paste on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, outlook, microsoft-edge, paste

We have a `input type="search"` field on our website that accepts a string of pasted emails from a Mac in all browsers tested (Safari, Brave, Chrome, Firefox, Edge) but will not accept string of email addresses copied from `To:` field in **Outlook** on **Windows 10** in Edge or Chrome.

The string will paste fine into a text editor but nothing happens when pasting into the input field and there are no errors in browser's console.

I'm guessing maybe there's formatting around the copied string or maybe it's an object of some Windows type? But I have no idea. How can one debug this? Can start with a way to examine the pasteboard (or clipboard or whatever Windows calls it).

Input field looks like this:

`<input aria-label="Search for option" role="combobox" type="search" autocomplete="off" class="vs__search">`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you try using https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028529/windows-10-clipboard to get a look at what the contents of the clipboard look like during this scenario?

Comment: I'm in favor of @sevensidedmarble's suggestion. You could try to check the clipboard history to see what you have copied. Besides, do you use the Outlook app or the web version? Which version of Edge are you using?